# Detecting the timed out client in select function

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, udp, posix-select

I want to use the `select` function to work with different file descriptors. When the program  starts, it must start sending packets to other clients in accordance to an interval. My first question is how can I employ a timer in the main while loop without interrupting the while loop and the select function's functionality? That is because I need to take the user inputs while the timer is running.

The second question is that I don't now if I need to put the send function in my while loop. Do I need to write the send function as the program enters the while loop or I need to use it somewhere else?

Also, the program must detect the file descriptors that have not been active for a specific time. How can I detect which file descriptors have not been sending any packets to the server?

Below you can see the codes that I have written so far. Could you please help me fix it?
I have not employed any timer here yet. Also, the program is unable to detect which file descriptor has timed out.

```
        FD_ZERO(&masterfds);
        FD_SET(udp_con, &masterfds);
        maxfds = udp_con;

        while(exit == false)
        { //Do I need to use the send function here?
            FD_ZERO(&readfds);
            readfds = masterfds;

            selectFunc = select(maxfds+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
            if(selectFunc < 0)
            {
                message("error in select");
                exit = true;
            }
            else if(selectFunc == 0)
            { //How can I detect which file descriptor is timed out?
                for(i = 0; i <= maxfds; i++)
                {
                    if(FD_ISSET(i, &readfds))
                    {
                        //Doesn't work
                        cout<<"The file descriptor "<<i<<" has timed out"<<endl;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            { //The server has received something from a client

                for(i = 0; i <= maxfds; i++)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The last argument of select is the amount of time to wait for events in the file descriptor set. You could use that to wait for a predefined period of time for events, say 100 ms. If that timeout passed without any events being received, select will return 0 and no descriptors will be set.

Now you need to think about what an 'active' connection means from the perspective of the server. Normally, you should keep a separate timestamp for each fd of when data was last *received* on that connection. Sending can happen without any problem and does not indicate the connection is still active.

So the code should be structured like this - some rough pseudocode:

```
select with timeout
did select return 0:
  (this means that no data was received for the timeout on any descriptor)
  (this is the place to check if any descriptor went past its 'active' limit)
  iterate over all fds:
    if last_received_timestamp[current_fd] + deadline > current_time:
      remove fd or do something else
else:
  (there is something to read)
  iterate over descriptors in readfds:
    read data and process it
    last_received_timestamp[current_fd] = current_time
```

Hope this helps.

Additional information:

If you want a more uniform way of dealing with this, try looking into timerfd_create. That can be used to create timers that look like file descriptors and so you can use select for them to get notified of certain events. For example, you can create one such timerfd for each normal fd you have and have it set to expire when the deadline is reached. The key here is to rearm the timer whenever you receive data.

A classic problem with single threaded loops like this that wait for events then process all of them sequentially is that if the server becomes too busy or if data processing for a connection takes too much, all connections will see delays. A better architecture is to use a thread pool for handling reading/writing on sockets. This frees up the event loop and gives better response times for all clients. However, this is more complex and probably outside the scope of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, but I was wondering since I am using UDP connections and  I don't use the accept function to get a new file descriptor for each client, do I need to add any file descriptor to my master FDs list?

I am a bit confused now. It seems that the only file descriptor that I am going to use is "udp_con". Is that correct?

Comment: I am using linux and just tried to include the header "sys/timerfd.h", but it cannot find any header with that name. How can I take the advantage of timerfd in linux?